# Code Highlighting in PHPStorm/WebStorm for Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, phpstorm, webstorm

In my controller, I have a function defined as:

```
var ProductListingHeaderController = function (FilterService, CategoryService) {
    this.isCategorySet = function () {
        return (FilterService.categoryID);
    };
    this.categoryName = function () {
        return (CategoryService.categoryName());
    };
};
```

The IDE (via code highlighting) reports **categoryName()** as being used and **isCategorySet()** as unused.

This is kind of understandable, since:

categoryName() is used inside `{{ }}` in the html file:

```
<h2>{{productListingHeader.categoryName()}}</h2>
```

and isCategorySet() is used in an ng-if string:

```
ng-if="productListingHeader.isCategorySet()"
```

Given that this is such a common usage, I suspect I may be missing a setting in Storm as to how to set things up so that this type of usage (inside a string) by an Angular directive gets picked up as "used".

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's normal behavior for PHP/WebStorm.

Template -> JavaScript is really just an ambiguous connection. There is no support for jsDoc type inferring in the AngularJS templates. So PHP/WebStorm will match a template function call to JavaScript if only that function name is unique.

PHP/WebStorm have issues inferring closure methods as object functions. I've had better success using prototype declaration for AngularJS controllers.

```
var ProductListingHeaderController = function (FilterService, CategoryService) {
    this.filterService = FilterService;
    this.categoryService = CategoryService;
}
ProductListingHeaderController.prototype.isCategorySet = function () {
    return (this.filterService.categoryID);
};
ProductListingHeaderController.prototype.categoryName = function () {
    return (this.categoryService.categoryName());
};
```

Compare the above code with your code, and look at the structure explore in WebStorm. When you use prototypes for controllers they appear in the explorer properly.